# Как поменять стандартный путь в терминале в pycharm?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

У меня есть проект Django в PyCharm и когда я его открываю, то путь в терминале у меня вот такой `C:\Users\Vladimir\PycharmProjects\RuArticles>`. Из-за чего мне постоянно приходится прописывать `cd .\RuArticles`. Можно чтобы он был такой изначально?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы изначально был `C:\Users\Vladimir\PycharmProjects\RuArticles\RuArticles>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На картинке php-storm, но у всех JB IDE эта настройка одинакова

Settings->Tools->Terminal->Start Derictory

[image: настройки]

Comment: К сожалению не работает метод. У меня указанное в пункте не совпадает с реальным. Обновление
Заработало после того как нажал на кнопку +
https://skr.sh/sEcRiJGkARh

Comment: после изменения надо было закрыть текущий терминал и открыть снова